How to save state of filter search performed on Tab using TabPanel with index 0 when moving back from TabPanel with index 1
I have a Function component where I have tabs designed in div as below. There are two tabs which are loaded with data when we land on the page and I have filtering turned on for both tabs. I can see the filter results. When I switch between the tabs, the filter tends to clear and not able to retain the values. Can someone help me with this?
<div>
    <AppBar position="unset" style={{ width: '90%', paddingLeft: '100px', display: 'inline-block' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
           <Tab label="1"></Tab>
           <Tab label="2"></Tab>
        </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
    <TabPanel style={{ fontSize: '12px' }} value={value} index={0} forceRender={true}>
     <MaterialTable> 
        key={tableKey}
                    tableRef={tableRef1}
                    title="Current"
                    columns={[
                      {
                        title: "ID",editable: false, field: "id", width: null, cellStyle: { width: 150, maxWidth: 150, minWidth: 150 }, filterCellStyle:{minWidth:150, maxWidth: 150}, //filtering: holdQuery[0] === "" ? true : false,
                        filterComponent: props => {
                          return (
                            <TextField
                              label={props.value}
                              style={{ width: 150, maxWidth: 150, minWidth: 150 }}
                              InputProps={{
                                type: 'search',
                                startAdornment: (
                                  <InputAdornment position="start" >
                                    <SearchIcon style={{ fontSize: '13px' }} />
                                  </InputAdornment>
                                ),
                              }}
                              onChange={(e) => { 
                                //  handleFilterChange(e, props); // by adding this piece filter is not working
                                 props.onFilterChanged(props.columnDef.tableData.id, e.target.value)
                              }}
                            />
                          )
                        },
                      },





